Relation between $\mathcal{M}(\omega^{CK}_1, X)$ and $L_{\omega^{CK}_1}[X]$
In Higher Recursion Theory there is a great deal of focus on the structure $\mathcal{M}(\omega^{CK}_1, X)$ (introduced by Feferman) but little said about $L_{\omega^{CK}_1}[X]$.  What Sacks says about it seems superficially similar to what other works says about $L_{\omega^{CK}_1}[X]$ (at least when $\omega^{CK, X}_1=\omega^{CK}_1$) but I haven't found any direct statement relating the two.
Is there some close relation between the two structures (if there is one does it still make sense when $\omega^{CK, X}_1\neq\omega^{CK}_1$)?  In particular, does $\mathcal{M}(\omega^{CK}_1, X)$ satisfy $\Delta^1_1$-comprehension iff $L_{\omega^{CK}_1}[X]$ does?
I'm groping a bit in the dark here so if there is some modification to the question that provides a more useful answer please interpret it that way.

Here is the definition for $\mathcal{M}(\alpha, X)$. It's pretty complicated as given but I think it basically reduces to the sets definable via a formula of rank at most $\alpha$ (or $< \alpha$ if $\alpha =  \omega^{CK}_1$).  Part of the complication in the definition shown below is likely that Sacks doesn't use the notion of computably infinitary formulas.



Will you give a definition of $\mathcal{M}(\alpha,X)$? I think it’s probably the powerset of $\omega$ intersected with $L_{\alpha}[X]$ (at least if $\alpha \leq \omega_1^{X}$).

@GabeGoldberg Maybe it is, that's something I'm trying to figure out, but I think it's basically the collection of sets definable via a formula of rank $\alpha$ from $X$.  In particular, if $\omega^{CK, X}_1 = \omega^{CK}_1$ then $\mathcal{M}( \omega^{CK}_1, X) = HYP(X)$

Yes, for $\alpha\le\omega_1^{CK}$ the structure $\mathscr{M}(\alpha,T)$ is just $L_\alpha[T]\cap\mathcal{P}(\omega)$. Moreover, for all $\alpha$ we have $\mathscr{M}(\alpha,T)\subseteq L_\alpha[T]\cap\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ and $\mathscr{M}(\alpha,T)\in L_{\alpha+1}[T]$.
The latter claim is an easy induction (since rank-$\beta$ quantifiers can just be interpreted as usual quantifiers bounded by $\mathscr{M}(\beta, T)$). The interesting part is the containment $\mathscr{M}(\alpha,T)\supseteq L_\alpha[T]\cap\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ when $\alpha$ is not too big. The point is that as long as $\alpha$ is small enough, elements of $L_\alpha[T]$ are appropriately coded by reals in $L_\alpha[T]$ and so quantification over $L_\alpha[T]\cap\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ is as powerful as quantification over $L_\alpha[T]$. However, this breaks down at the ordinal $\beta_0+2$ at the latest: in going from $\beta_0$ to $\beta_0+1$ there is a change in the $L$-hierarchy not visible in the reals ("$\beta_0$ starts a length-1 gap"), but then in $L_{\beta_0+2}$ we gain a new real.
